# Session Invalidation in node.js with passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Evaluating passport for nodejs; it's my understanding that *deserializeUser* will be called every request using the middleware and that it will typically make a DB request for that user. This almost reminds me of a polling request.

Why don't User update methods simply invalidate individual sessions, triggering a new read at that time alone, assuming no large batch user modifications or frequent user changes? Would it not significantly cut reads in exchange for a mote of updates?